# ForeignKeys & JOIN - не работает запрос

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, gino

Такая проблема, использую PostgreSQL & GINO и сейчас пытаюсь в джоины.

У меня имеются две модели, Game & User. Пытаюсь выбрать игры, в которых:

1. Нет противника
2. Такая же валюта игры
3. Опыт хоста игры больше или меньше заданного промежутка.

Должен получиться примерно такой запрос (написан на MySQL мне нужно переписать под PostgreSQL):

```sql
SELECT g.id       AS id_0,
       g.currency AS currency_1,
       g.user_id   AS user_id
FROM games g
         INNER JOIN users u1_ ON g.user_id = u1_.id
WHERE (u1_.experience BETWEEN ? AND ?)
  AND g.currency = ?
  AND g.enemy_id IS NULL
  AND g.winner_id IS NULL
ORDER BY g.id ASC
```

Делаю запрос так:

```py
async def find_pending_game(user: User, currency: str):
    ...
    return await Game.join(User).select().where(User.experience.between(min_experience, max_experience),
                                                         Game.currency == currency,
                                                         Game.enemy_id is None,
                                                         Game.winner_id is None).all()
```

Модели:
**user.py**

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from sqlalchemy.sql import expression

from app.models.db import BaseModel, TimedBaseModel, db


class User(TimedBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)
    ...

class UserRelatedModel(BaseModel):
    __abstract__ = True

    user_id = db.Column(
        db.ForeignKey(f"{User.__tablename__}.id", ondelete="CASCADE", onupdate="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False,
    )
```

**game.py**

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from app.models.db import BaseModel, TimedBaseModel, db


class Game(TimedBaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "games"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, unique=True)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stocks.id'))
    enemy_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    enemy_stock_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('stocks.id'))
    winner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    ...


class GameRelatedModel(BaseModel):
    __abstract__ = True

    game_id = db.Column(
        db.ForeignKey(f"{Game.__tablename__}.id", ondelete="CASCADE", onupdate="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False,
    )
```

**db.py**

```py
import datetime
from typing import List

import sqlalchemy as sa
from gino import Gino

from app import config

db = Gino()


class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    def __str__(self):
        model = self.__class__.__name__
        table: sa.Table = sa.inspect(self.__class__)
        primary_key_columns: List[sa.Column] = table.primary_key.columns
        values = {
            column.name: getattr(self, self._column_name_map[column.name])
            for column in primary_key_columns
        }
        values_str = " ".join(f"{name}={value!r}" for name, value in values.items())
        return f"<{model} {values_str}>"


class TimedBaseModel(BaseModel):
    __abstract__ = True

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(True), server_default=db.func.now())
    updated_at = db.Column(
        db.DateTime(True),
        default=datetime.datetime.utcnow,
        onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow,
        server_default=db.func.now(),
    )
...
```

Но в итоге получаю ошибку.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Can't determine join between 'games' and 'users'; tables have more than one foreign key constraint relationship between them. Please specify the 'onclause' of this join explicitly.
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: Не понятно что вы пытаетесь сделать, можете дополнить описание?
Можете адаптировать пример, чтобы его можно было запустить? (например скопировав его к себе)

Comment: @AndrewHolovko при запуске кода из repository.py, получаю ошибку. Модели так же указал, которые использую :)

Comment: TimedBaseModel это что за модель?
`from app.models.db import BaseModel, TimedBaseModel, db`

Comment: @AndrewHolovko точно, я забыл, извиняюсь. Апдейтнул вопрос

Comment: У Вас в таблице(модели) `Games` много полей являются внешними ключами ссылающимися на одно и то же поле таблицы `Users` - на `users.id`. О чем Вам и сигнализирует ошибка, нельзя однозначно сджойнить эти две таблицы.

Comment: @asanisimov есть такая же структура таблиц на MySQL, запрос там работает полностью. Добавил его в вопрос. Неужели в Postgre это невозможно?

Comment: @MyZik все везде возможно, в sql запросе Вы явно указываете условия джойна `INNER JOIN users u1_ ON g.user_id = u1_.id`, а в ORM `Game.join(User)` нет, машина не может однозначно понять по какому условию джойнить.

Comment: @asanisimov я полагаю, что метод join в SQLalchemy и GINO это и делает.

Comment: @asanisimov как можно тогда поправить мой код, исходя из условий задачи?

Comment: @MyZik да, но я Вам в 1-ом коментарии указал проблему, ваша модель `Game` ссылается внешним ключем на `users.id` в нескольких полях - `user_id`, `enemy_id`, `winner_id`  - это и есть ошибка. enemy и winner должны ссылаться на другие таблицы/поля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему:

```py
await Game.join(User, User.id == Game.user_id).select().where(
        and_(
            between(User.experience, min_experience, max_experience),
            Game.currency == currency,
            Game.enemy_id == None,
            Game.winner_id == None
        )
    ).gino.all()
```